# Remove line UISearchBar with UISearchDisplayController when remove the background color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have added with help of interface builder a `UISearchBar` With `UISearchDisplayController` in my `UITableView`. I know how to set the background color of `UISearchBar`, I do it this way:

```
for (UIView *subview in self.searchBar.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) {

            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
```

but you can see, there is a line, that I can't understand , and how to remove it, that scroll with the searchbar:

[image]

if I insert with interface builder only a `UISearchbar` without `UISearchDisplayController` there isn't that line, how I can remove that line?

Answer (score 3):

Use this instead:

```
  for (UIView *subview in self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.subviews) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) {

      [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
  }
```

When we use `UISearchDisplayController`, the searchBar gets associated with the searchBar property of UISearchDisplayController and can be accessed using  `self.searchDisplayController.searchBar`

Comment: Yes, I have just tried. It removed the background View of search bar.

Comment: Why are you not getting a compilation error on this line self.searchBar? Have you made a separate property and connected the Search Bar from nib to your property?

Comment: i have add the uisearchbar with displaycontroller to the uitableview in interface builder, then from interface builder i have make the connection to the owner view...

Comment: When you drag Search Bar and Search Display Controller from Objects library to your nib, you get a search bar associated with Search Display Controller. The Search bar in that case is linked with SearchDisplayController object, and which you can access through self.searchDisplayController.searchBar. You dont need to make a separate IBOUTLET to a search bar property. That defeats the purpose of using SearchDisplayController. Infact dont even create an IBOutlet for Search Display Controller as it is done automatically.

Comment: i understand, i remove all, and i started again, i add UISearchBar and UISearchDisplayController to the uitableview in interface builder, and i haven't make any IBOutlet, and i use your code in the answer, and the line is still there...

Comment: i don't think you have tried your code...because believe me but the line is always there, i have create a sample project and add only that few thing, and doesn't work...

Comment: Believe me I have tried it, but tell me one thing if you remove UISearchBarBackground then you must be getting an all black background. Clean/ build your project.

Comment: here is the simple project, tried it and tell me if you see that line...https://www.dropbox.com/s/n2lympsnnpzi8pa/bha.zip

Comment: Unfortunately I cant access your project at my workplace. But I am sure you will find your solution. Keep looking.

Comment: i make another simple project using Xcode 4, so you can use it, maybe there you doens't have the developer preview, this is the link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m5wqxrg39wfru19/Bha2.zip i can't think i'm find a solution alone, if you can take a look please, thanks...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35908/discussion-between-puneet-and-piero)

Answer (score 1):

I am using 1px image with 0% opacity [(image)](http://imgur.com/download/ktAzSXe)

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.backgroundImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"] ;
```

and its work perfect as what you want.